# Keras Text Classification: Validation Accuracy doesn't change

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So, I'm building a basic Keras Text Classifier but no matter what I do I cannot get the validation accuracy to be any higher than 49-50% (or lower for that matter). My training accuracy climbs pretty normally, starting at around 50% and climbing to 80% or so after 4-5 epochs.

Here is an example of output:

```
 - 54s - loss: 0.6982 - acc: 0.5064 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.4950
Epoch 2/3
 - 57s - loss: 0.6560 - acc: 0.6580 - val_loss: 0.7324 - val_acc: 0.4950
Epoch 3/3
 - 60s - loss: 0.5359 - acc: 0.7047 - val_loss: 0.7339 - val_acc: 0.4955
```

And here is my code:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from keras import optimizers
np.random.seed(7)
class TextClassifier:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 5000)
        self.top_words = 5000
        self.max_words = 500
        self.model = model = Sequential()
        model.add(Embedding(self.top_words,64,input_length = self.max_words))
        model.add(Conv1D(filters = 64,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(250,activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer = 'adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])

    def train(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
        self.model.fit(X_train,y_train, shuffle = True,
        validation_data = (X_test,y_test),epochs = 3,batch_size=512,verbose = 2)

    def predict(self,X):
        return self.model.predict(X)

    def init_tokenizer(self,X):
        self.tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)

    def eval(self,X,y):
        return self.model.evaluate(X, y, verbose=0)

    def proccess_text(self,X):
        vocab_text = self.tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)
        vocab_text = sequence.pad_sequences(vocab_text,maxlen=500)
        return vocab_text

    def organize_text(self,pos_path,neg_path):
        data = {'label':[],'text':[]}
        pos_texts = self.text_to_array(pos_path)
        neg_texts = self.text_to_array(neg_path)
        for i in pos_texts:
            data['label'].append(0)
            data['text'].append(i)
        for i in neg_texts:
            data['label'].append(1)
            data['text'].append(i)
        return data

    def text_to_array(self,path):
            ''' Takes a path argument and retrieves all the text lines from
                within a folder'''
            name_list = []
            texts = []
            for file_ in os.listdir(path):
                name_list.append(file_)
            for i in name_list:
                file_ = open(path+i)
                texts.append(file_.read().splitlines())
            return texts





from TextClassifier import *

path = './data/train/'
test_path = './data/test/'
model = TextClassifier()

data = model.organize_text(path+'pos/',path+'neg/')
tests = model.organize_text(test_path+'pos/',test_path+'neg/')
model.init_tokenizer(data['text'])
model.init_tokenizer(tests['text'])
X_train  = np.array(model.proccess_text(data['text']))
X_test = np.array(model.proccess_text(tests['text']))
y_train = data['label']
y_test = tests['label']
model.train(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test)
scores = model.eval(X_test,y_test)
input_ = model.proccess_text(['It was very good! Awesome! Enjoyable!'])
print("Predict: ")
predict = model.predict(input_)
print(predict)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

My corpus is from here:http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/ and I'm just splitting the first 1000 for each class as validation data. (They're unordered afaik)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how much Dropout(0.5) is helping your model.  It seems that BatchNormalization() may be a good replacement.  You may want to consider a LSTM layer after your the embedding layer.  You can add dropout to LSTM directly.  E.g.:

model.add(LSTM(lstm_out, dropout_U=0.2, dropout_W=0.2))

For a nice full example, I'd invite you to review this model:
https://www.kaggle.com/ngyptr/lstm-sentiment-analysis-keras

Hope this helps and good luck!

Edit: Based on my comment below

I think your model may be training on non-character tokens because if you use this text_to_array(self,path) function, your validation accuracy is .79, .85, and .87:

```
    import re
def text_to_array(self,path):
            ''' Takes a path argument and retrieves all the text lines from
                within a folder'''
            name_list = []
            texts = []
            for file_ in os.listdir(path):
                name_list.append(file_)
            for i in name_list:
                file_ = open(path+i)
                for line in file_.read().splitlines():
                    # I just preprocessed your text here
                    texts.append(re.sub('[^a-zA-z0-9\s]','',line.lower()))
            return texts
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I have quick question. Shouldn't the val acc at least be changing a little bit though? I don't understand how my training accuracy can be as high as 85% but my validation accuracy is literally always between 49% - 50%. I wouldn't even be upset if my validation accuracy was super low as long as it showed change but as it stands I cannot move it off of 50%. I'll take a look at your link!

Comment: I was able to replicate your issue using the Stanford Sentiment data.  I followed my above guidances but still ran into the same issue you reported.  I then preprocessed the text and adapted the learning rate and boom, validation accuracy rose from .5446 to .5675 after the first and second epochs respectively. I'll update my answer above shortly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've had to focus on some school projects. That looks awesome! Thank you so much for the help- I'll look into it more in-depth when I get some free time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest moving the dropout to the dense layer and adding some more conv layers. Part of learning is playing around.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of different layers but my validation is always either 49% or 50%. I'm just confused because I can't seem to get it below that (without purposely gimping my model) or even a single point above that.